# Unpack strip into combination of integer and list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have strings similar to `1 2 3 4 5 6` and I can unpack them like this:

```
id, amount, p0, p1, p2, p3 = [int(i) for i in s.split()]
```

Now I put p0 - p3 in a temporary list `list = [p0, p1, p2, p3]` and iterate over it. Is there an elegant way to skip the last step and do the same for `x` variables:

```
id, amount, list = ...
```

Comment: Don't name your own variable `list`, it shadows the built-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `*` to capture the 'remaining' values into one variable:

```
id, amount, *p_values = [int(i) for i in s.split()]
```

Python allows for 1 such variable when assigning; it'll get all the remaining values from the right-hand-side after all the other names without `*` have received a value:

```
>>> foo, bar, *baz = range(5)
>>> foo, bar, baz
(0, 1, [2, 3, 4])
>>> foo, *bar, baz = range(5)
>>> foo, bar, baz
(0, [1, 2, 3], 4)
>>> *foo, bar, baz = range(5)
>>> foo, bar, baz
([0, 1, 2], 3, 4)
```

See the [PEP-3132 *Extended Iterable Unpacking*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132):

> A tuple (or list) on the left side of a simple assignment (unpacking is not defined for augmented assignment) may contain at most one expression prepended with a single asterisk (which is henceforth called a "starred" expression, while the other expressions in the list are called "mandatory"). This designates a subexpression that will be assigned a list of all items from the iterable being unpacked that are not assigned to any of the mandatory expressions, or an empty list if there are no such items.

Answer (score 0):

The "elegance" of this method is debate-able at best.  But you could do something like:

```
list = [int(i) for i in s.split()]
id = list.pop(0)
amount = list.pop(0)
```

This actually is more lines of code, but if you're trailing list of ints is very long you wouldn't have to type out such a long series of `p1,p2,p3...` and put it into another list